# Web Publishing using Apache2

Tags: 14.04

I recently installed apache2 in my laptop to host a website. I tried creating a html page and published it. But when I type the link on the browser it tells me the website dosen,t exist. Can someone suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you put your files into "/var/www/html/" or "/var/www" (depending on how you have Apache set up) if you are connecting over a local network make sure you are using the local IP address of the computer and not your public IP. To get the local IP of the computer type in "ifconfig" and it should be like 192.168.1.6 or something. If you are connecting over the internet make sure you properly port forwarded port 80 and are using your public IP, not your local IP. If you can reach the website locally but not over different networks, and you port forwarded port 80, then your ISP might have blocked port 80. Basically, if you are connecting to a PC in the same house, try using the local IP.

Comment: Port 80 could be also blocked by firewall or can be used by another program he should check that also.